# Call Excel Macro from Ribbon Button

Tags: c#, xml, excel, vsto, ribbon

I have a VBA Macro that works perfect in excel via a button, but i want to include a button in the excel ribbon(which i have done) but i do not know how to connect the ribbon button to the macro correctly, here is my C# and XML code:

C#

```
public class Ribbon1 : Office.IRibbonExtensibility
{
    private Office.IRibbonUI ribbon;

    TimeSpan startTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0);

    TimeSpan timeDecrease = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
    {
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        this.ribbon = ribbonUI;
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (startTimeSpan.ToString() != "00:00:00")
        {
            startTimeSpan = startTimeSpan - timeDecrease;
            ribbon.InvalidateControl("timerLabel");
        }
        else
        {
            startTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0);
            return;
        }
    }

    public string timerLabel_getLabel(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        return startTimeSpan.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_onAction(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.Run("'PM MailMerge.xlsm'!MailMerge.MailMerge");
    }
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" >
<ribbon>
<tabs>
  <tab  id="TimerTest" 
        label="Practice Monitoring">
    <group  id="group1" 
            label="MailMerge">
      <labelControl id="timerLabel" 
                     getLabel="timerLabel_getLabel"/>
      <button   id="button1" 
                label="Merge" 
                size="large" 
                onAction="'PM MailMerge.xlsm'!MailMerge.MailMerge"/>
    </group>
  </tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will run the macro from the current opened excel workbook or macro from the workbook available in xlstart(C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART) folder

```
 Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.Run("Your macroname")
```

Comment: cant seem to get that to work, and wherabouts is the xlstart folder? I am not using customUI Editor

Comment: where is your macro? Is it in the same document that you are customizing by adding ribbon controls?

Comment: Just pass in your macro name as a parameter

Comment: check out my edit, it shows the new code, the button1 "onAction" shows the macro name in the XML, and i have added the line you have given me with the macro name, taken straight from excel

Comment: onAction="'PM MailMerge.xlsm'!MailMerge.MailMerge" in Ribbon.xml has to be onAction="button1_onAction"

Comment: thanks, anything else there you can see to be wrong?  still not running. I changed button1_onAction to just MessageBox.Show("test") and still nothing appears

Comment: Add try catch on your button1_onAction method and find if there is any exception.

Comment: realised the issue, was set as a private void, set it to public and perfecto. Thanks +1