# How (or is it possible) to call VBA (sub or function) from ribbon added to Excel through VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vsto, add-in

I am working on a project where I have a Visual Studio C# Excel Add-in project (VSTO). From the VSTO code I am adding a Ribbon with a button to Excel (Office.IRibbonExtensibility).
From the so added button in Excel I can make callback calls to methods in the C# code (in the VSTO add-in).
I am looking (and not finding) for the way to call VBA (sub of function) from that button to VBA code that is in the Excel file.
In other words, from that described button I know how to call code that is in C# but don't know how to call VBA code that is in the Excel file itself.
I spent quite some time searching for information and testing some blind ideas but no success either finding anything or getting some good results from my tests.
I would appreciate a kick start in the right direction.

Not sure if this the right place and way to add this later (2/10/20 @17:08 GMT -7) note (after getting the answers below). I have created a small demo project and uploaded it on github. There is a video (mp4) file in the project too to show how it works.
https://github.com/MNemteanu/ExcelVSTOAddInDemo

Comment: You can't call C# which then calls the VBA?  Maybe you could explain a little more about your use case.

Comment: I thought about that but can't tell if and how that would work. That would be a plan B. It would be a work-around (literally) because both the button and the VBA are in the Excel file and makes more sense to call directly from the button to the VBA rather than going button  -> C# -> VBA. I'm just hoping (still) to find a direct call solution.
If would explain the use case it would become to hairy but would gladly add clarifications if any specific question is asked.

Comment: Looks relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428977/call-excel-macro-from-ribbon-button

Comment: Thanks for the link Tim, I saw that and tried and does not work.
If I would have to rely on this 12 years old information (I guess nobody is in charge to clean up the Internet) I should start working on the plan B. This guy says that the call-back must be to the COM Add-in not to the VBA: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/96e1c1f8-8707-45e4-8efd-b1347288173b/managed-com-addin-callbacks-to-document-vba?forum=vsto

Comment: Is the aim to add the ribbon and have it persist (and be able to trigger the macro) after the VSTO add-in is unloaded?  BTW 12 years isn't that long in excel-land...

Comment: @TimWilliams ^^ Nor in VSTO-land since the technology hasn't been updated for quite a while (and won't be).

Comment: I'm not in a position to look at this, at the moment (mobile device) but right off-hand, if none of the suggestions here in comments or the links are what you're looking for then the only alternative that comes to mind: User RibbonXML, not the VSTO Designer. Identify the tab, group and controls that should be *shared* using the `idQ` attribute. This way, Ribbon XML in other solutions can use the same elements. Put the corresponding Ribbon XML in the Excel workbook with the VBA. In that way the same Ribbon should be able to use the VSTO code / VBA code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible.
You have to note that VBA code is stored in particular workbook whilst VSTO add-in is loaded within application, despite of the active workbook. And none of both knows about each other, unless developer does.
In order to implement such interaction you have to know following:
1. Macro holding workbook's name;
2. Macro name.

Knowing this you will be able to apply solution posted in 3d comment.
Below is an example.
Prerequisites:
1. I have prepared macro-enabled workbook "VBA.xlsm";
2. This workbook has a macro called "Foo" in regular module.

Implementation:
1. Create new VSTO add-in;
2. Add Ribbon (Visual Designer) called "Ribbon1" and setup it to have "Custom" ControlIdType (to be a separate tab called "Test");
3. Add a button named "callVBA" to that ribbon which will check the name of the book and try to run workbook's macro.

I didn't add any code to ThisAddIn.cs class. The only code I used - is in the button click event handler in the Ribbon class:

```
public partial class Ribbon1
    {
        private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void callVBA_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name == "VBA.xlsm")
            {
                Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks["VBA.xlsm"].Application.Run("Foo");
            }
        }
    }
```

That's pretty easy, but requires that you have prepared prerequisites.
How it works:
[image]

**Update 1**

Here is more complex approach which checks open workbooks and enables/disables specific button based on whether there is a workbook with needed macro. It also checks newly opened and handles recently closed workbooks with only one `Workbook_Activate` event.
If you don't do any check - you may get a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` with a

> Message=Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus.

```cs
 public partial class Ribbon1
    {
        private bool vbaMacroFound;

        private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckButtons();
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.WorkbookActivate += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookActivateEventHandler(Workbook_Activate);
        }

        private void callVBA_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            if (vbaMacroFound)
            {
                Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks["VBA.xlsm"].Application.Run("Foo");
            }
        }

        private void Workbook_Activate(Excel.Workbook Wb)
        {
            CheckButtons();
        }

        private void CheckButtons()
        {
            vbaMacroFound = false;
            this.callVBA.Enabled = false;
            this.callVBA.ScreenTip = "There is no specified macro in none of active workbooks";

            foreach (Excel.Workbook book in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks)
            {

                if (book.Name.Equals("VBA.xlsm"))
                {
                    this.callVBA.Enabled = true;
                    this.callVBA.ScreenTip = "Call the sub from VBA";
                    vbaMacroFound = true;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Vitaliy for taking the time to prepare such a detailed answer. This really makes a difference especially when someone like me doesn't have enough experience in the matter to be able to follow with a less detailed answer.

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams for your answers too, sorry for not being able to follow up with your hints without more help.

Comment: Hi @VitaliyPrushak & Tim Williams just a quick FYI, see the late note at the bottom of my initial question. Not sure where should I put that note for others who may search for the same information.
Thanks again and looking forward fore more good help from you.